# Side collison detection with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to add side collison detection beetwen my player and bricks that are gereted.
[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-smoke-8qh0o?file=/src/collision.js)
So in my code sanbox i put all my code just to not add all here. I have `collision.js` where all collision are handeled. The general collisions are working, but i want to add plauer stopn whe it hit side of my brick.
I have implementd something like this

```
  //* sied checks
  if (
    playerLeft >= objectRightSide &&
    playerLeft >= objectLeft &&
    playerRight === objectLeftSide &&
    playerRight <= objectRight
  ) {
    player.position.x = gameObejct.position.x + player.width;
  }
```

But this is not working at all. I was trying diffenert things but nothing was working as it should :/

Answer (score 0):

You will not make the simple approach work. This problem is harder than it looks.

Firstly, the boolean operations are wrong.

Secondly - if you think about it logically: to make the player stop at the collision boundaries, you **must** include player speed (or equivalent, like the last position) in the equations - somehow. Otherwise, no matter from which side the collision happens, you will move the player to the same spot, which is obviously wrong.

As I stated, the collision and displacement algorithms are trickier than they seem (and they can affect the game play), to get a feel for them you will need to use some external resource.

Comment: hmm, thanks. Will double check and work with speed